# conversion of English input to Urdu & Turkish in code igniter

Tags: codeigniter, google-translate, google-translation-api

In my code igniter application I want to convert the English input to Urdu & Turkish. Can some one please tell how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at to the sample code on using Translation API with PHP [[1]](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/master/translate/src/translate.php) and also you can look at this official documentation for more details [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/translating-text).

I haven’t tried this but this example uses Codeigniter and Translation API that might be useful to you [[3]](http://www.dbjohn.com/blogs/google-translate-api-v2-and-codeigniter).

Comment: Let me know if this answers your question. If you have a specific problem you can comment about it. Follow this guide [link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a question, which will increase your chance to receive a good answer.